# Smoothing OSB subfloor after hardwood and glue removal

Tags: flooring

We are in process of installing new nail-down solid bamboo floors in the first floor of our home.  This has required us to remove the existing glued-down engineered hardwood from the kitchen area.

We've removed the floor and glue, but the glue took some of the subfloor in the process.  Wondering what the best way would be to patch the subfloor to be smooth?

I thought about putting down a skim coat of something like FeatherFinish, but wondering if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are just a few patches here and there where it ripped out parts of the subfloor, something like FeatherFinish may be acceptable.

Personally, I have seen and have used 1/8" Lauan underlayment on rough surfaces or where the subfloor has been damaged. It is easy to install and creates an extremely smooth surface for adhesive tiles, laminated flooring, or engineered / hardwood floors.